# Bypass prev / next links based on front matter value?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm running a Jekyll based blog and at the bottom of my blog posts I have previous and next post links. Here's what that looks like:

```
<div class="post-nav full-bleed">
  <div>
    {% if page.previous.url %}
    <p><-- The one before<br>
    <a href="{{page.previous.url}}">{{page.previous.title}}</a></p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class="post-nav-next">
    {% if page.next.url %}
    <p> Up next --><br>
    <a href="{{page.next.url}}">{{page.next.title}}</a></p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

However I publish RSS only posts on my blog that are hidden from the main blog feed. To hide them I have a piece of front matter called 'rss_only' that has a value of true/false.

What I would like to do is hide those posts from my previous/next links too. I have edited the code to as shown below to try and hide the items, but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
<div class="post-nav full-bleed">
  <div>
    {% if page.previous.url %}
    {% assign previous = page.previous.url | where_exp: "item", "item.rss_only != true" %}
    <p><-- The one before<br>
    <a href="{{page.previous.url}}">{{page.previous.title}}</a></p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class="post-nav-next">
    {% if page.next.url %}
    {% assign next = page.next.url | where_exp: "item", "item.rss_only != true" %}
    <p> Up next --><br>
    <a href="{{page.next.url}}">{{page.next.title}}</a></p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like is for the previous or next item to be hidden if `rss_only` is `true` and skip over to the next post in the list and display a link to that.

I may be asking too much here, but any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way I could think of is to create a [collection](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) for rss_only posts and in the config, [set `output: false`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#output) to not render these pages. With this, you might have to adjust your RSS generation logic a bit to include these files in RSS.

Comment: That might just work. I'll give that a try and will report back. Thanks.